# Change Height of element in CSS Grid without pushing sibling elements

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm working with CSS Grids and want to create following layout. There could be `n` number of elements inside the wrapper. When we hover over on them it grows in height and shows shows more info. Pushing elements in the same `column`. Please refer to image below.

I'm not able to achieve with following CSS

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: start;
}
```

Please Help!

[image: Layout trying to achieve]

Comment: You don't need to use flex wrap when using grid. I don't think you'll be able to achieve what you want with grid as it essentially breaks the grid to only make 1 larger. Maybe try flex and change the direction?

Comment: Great suggestion @dpDesignz. But what means adding extra checks/ media query for smaller screens.

Comment: I agree with @dpDesignz. With grid layout, when you try to play with `width` and `height` of one grid cell, it applies to the entire row / column.

Answer (score 2):

changing the children's height changes the grid. So the solution here would be to add another DIV inside the children, which will be absolutely positioned. This way, you can make the height bigger while avoiding changing the original grid.

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: start;
}

.child {
    min-height: 150px;
    background: skyblue;
    position: relative;
    &--inner {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 22;
        transition: 0.2s height linear;
        &:hover {
            height: 150%;
        }
    }
}
```

example: https://codepen.io/lurx/pen/OJLRVQM

Comment: Rotem this will not solve the problem. As now, the children will overlap and gaps will not be respected. I guess grids cannot be used for these layouts.

Comment: I missed that what you wanted to do... yeah, I would use flex for this.

Comment: I will be blown away if someone achieves this with grids.

Comment: A little creative thinking, with two nested grids, allows you to do this, with two caveats: 1. There has to be a minimum height. 2. the grid is not transitionable, so no transition can be applied (there are JS solutions for that out there)

https://codepen.io/lurx/pen/mdbraEp

Comment: (pushing the bottom row down will not work with grid anyway, since it breaks the layout)